# How do I select the 2nd link in a nav element that has no ID or class?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbs" role="navigation" class="breadcrumb">
     <a href="/" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:291}" data-impressed="1">Home</a>
     <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <a href="/chicago-il">Chicago, IL</a>
     <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <span>Cpa</span>
</nav>
```

I always want to select the 2nd link (aka `<a href="/chicago-il">Chicago, IL</a>`).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the nth-child selector, or in your case a lot of selectors can apply, but this way you will always target the second

```
.nav a:nth-child(2) {
  /* css here */
}
```

Comment: Ahh kewl. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

In order to select the second anchor you may use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element

The snippet is:

```css
nav a:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbs" role="navigation" class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="/" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:291}" data-impressed="1">Home</a>
    <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a href="/chicago-il">Chicago, IL</a>
    <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Cpa</span>
</nav>
```

Instead if you want to use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

> he :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in the series of children matches the pattern an+b.

The snippet is:

```css
nav a:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbs" role="navigation" class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="/" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:291}" data-impressed="1">Home</a>
    <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a href="/chicago-il">Chicago, IL</a>
    <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Cpa</span>
</nav>
```

Comment: Very thorough & descriptive. Thanks much.